# Managing website passwords for small team

Tags: passwords, password-management

I'm part of a small group of people who manage a website and the server it runs on. We have many accounts with third-party websites or services that multiple people on the team need to access. What is the best practice password policy to use in this situation? The policy needs to accommodate many accounts on other sites (say, more than a dozen), as well as how the passwords are shared among team members (and changed if members leave).

**Edit:** To response to this.josh's comment, as I mentioned, more than 10 third-party accounts. Most of the accounts are standard password-protected accounts where there must be one for the whole team (these are services associated with the website as a whole, like the Amazon Affiliates program or reCAPTCHA). The services provided vary, few are critical, but they are still important to protect.

Comment: How many third party accounts do you have? What type of account controls do the third parties provide? Are you only allowed one account per third party website/service? What capabilites do these accounts provide: functions critical to your website, ancillary to your website, data backup, databasse services?

Comment: If you want to give access to specific people to specific passwords and keep track who has access to what I'm afraid there are no free solutions. There are few enterprise password managers: Hitachi: http://hitachi-id.com/password-manager/ or Passwordstate: http://www.clickstudios.com.au/

Comment: As Hubert Kario mentioned, [Passwordstate](http://www.clickstudios.com.au) by Click Studios will provide the functionality you're after and it is FREE for up to 5 user accounts, with no time limits.

Comment: Hi @Mark, welcome to the site! Please see the [FAQ#promotion] wrt disclosing your affiliation with a product. Aside from that, answers are intended to *answer* the question, please see [answer]. Hope you stick around and share some more info!

Comment: @jrdioko, can I assume you were not asking for a list of products, but rather how to form a relevant policy? If so can you please edit the question to emphasize that, as all  4 answers so far have done just that. If it is what you wanted, this should be community-wiki (any moderator can do this), as that would be a "shopping question".

Comment: @AviD: Well, the policy including its implementation. Some answers wouldn't involve products (e.g. use the same password everywhere, but change it often), others would (e.g. use a password manager that accommodates multiple users sharing passwords).

Comment: @jrdioko Policy should always be seperated from implemenation... even if one chooses to use X product, the question of what policy should be, still remains. You should first define your policy (and requirements), and then look for a tool that fits that.

Comment: Hi AviD, sorry I should have read your FAQ first as suggested, and yes I am one of the developers for Passwordstate. My intention regarding the free license information was to let jrdioko know it may be suited to his requirements as we offer it free for a small team of people. If anybody else has any questions, I'd be only to glad to assist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would highly recommend using a variant of KeePass. I use [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/), it will allow you to keep a local repository of all of your passwords and sensitive information encrypted and accessible to all of your team members.

I have been using KeePassX at work for about a year now and have had no complaints.

Comment: I just looked at KeepassX and some things look a little outdated, is it still under active development?

Comment: Yes, it is actively under development. The software is on its way to its second major release, [here](http://www.keepassx.org/news).

Comment: KeePass works poorly in a multi-user setting, since only one person can add or edit passwords at a time.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [Secret Server](http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html). Auditing is built in. It will also remember when the password was changed last, and it will remind you when a preset time is up (I.E 30 days) Also you can use roles to choose who has access to certain passwords.

Comment: The auditing functionality is essential (IMO)

Answer (score 4):

[Meldium](https://www.meldium.com/) recently popped up on my radar.  One unique thing is that they can automatically provision a new user when you onboard a new employee giving him/her access to all that they need.

Answer (score 0):

I have to revise my comment. There are solutions for password management and sharing: [Passpack](https://www.passpack.com/) for small groups it's cheap (4$ a month).

Unfortunately it doesn't provide auditing and doesn't remember when the password was last set.

Comment: Your website is currently down. Does the product even still exist?

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issue, and decided to build [Pocketvau.lt](https://www.pocketvau.lt). This had been a pain point for us for quite a few years and existing solutions just didn't solve the issue in a way that we were comfortable with.

(Full disclosure: I'm the founder)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [CommonKey](http://commonkey.com). They allow you to group users into teams and share accounts. I think it's free for up to a handful of sharing too.